# Identify items in a QGridLayout in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qgridlayout

I am tryin to create a simple calculator in PyQt, I am a newbie to PyQt. I have used QGridLayout to display the buttons and now I want to create the signals and the slots such that when the user clicks button2 ,2 displays in the QLineEdit. I have been trying to identify the individual buttons in the grid so I can create the slots for it but I am stuck. Here is a code snippet:

```
for num in range(1,9):
    grid.itemAt(num)=widget

widget.clicked.connect(Display_0)
```

the error is can't assign to function call. Please help I have researched and researched about it and once when I was experimenting I got an error, QWidgetItem does not have the attribute clicked.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help here.

In your code, grid.itemAt(num) is the execution of the function grid.itemAt. Assigning the widget variable to the execution of a function doesn't make much sense. Maybe you meant this instead?

```
widget=grid.itemAt(num)
```

This assigns the output of grid.itemAt(num) to the widget variable.

Hope this helps!